# Working Docusign API call - Need to add in-person signing capabilities

Tags: docusignapi

This is an example Docusign provided that I was able to test and make work in my environment. I need to add an in-person signing capabilities and I'm not sure how to adapt this so it will work in that scenario. IF anyone is willing to provide some assistance I'd appreciate it.

```
namespace Docusign
{
    public class RequestSignatureOnDocument
    {
        public static void DocusignPurchasingDocument()
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // ENTER VALUES FOR THE FOLLOWING 6 VARIABLES:
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string username = "api_user@mycompany.com";         // your account email
            string password = "**********************";         // your account password
            string integratorKey = "*******************";           // your account Integrator Key (found on Preferences -> API page)
            string recipientName = "Recipient";         // recipient (signer) name
            string recipientEmail = "recipient@someperson.com";         // recipient (signer) email
            string documentName = "MasterContract.docx";            // copy document with same name and extension into project directory (i.e. "test.pdf")
            string contentType = "application/docx";        // default content type is PDF
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // additional variable declarations
            string baseURL = "";            // - we will retrieve this through the Login API call

            try
            {
                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================

                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

                // set request url, method, and headers.  No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);

                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);

                // parse baseUrl from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));

                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 2 - Send Signature Request from Template
                //============================================================================

                /*
                    This is the only DocuSign API call that requires a "multipart/form-data" content type.  We will be 
                    constructing a request body in the following format (each newline is a CRLF):

                    --AAA
                    Content-Type: application/xml
                    Content-Disposition: form-data

                    <XML BODY GOES HERE>
                    --AAA
                    Content-Type:application/pdf
                    Content-Disposition: file; filename="document.pdf"; documentid=1 

                    <DOCUMENT BYTES GO HERE>
                    --AAA--
                 */

                // append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use for signature request api call
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes";

                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body (JSON also accepted)
                // .. following body adds one signer and places a signature tab 100 pixels to the right
                // and 100 pixels down from the top left corner of the document you supply
                string xmlBody =
                    "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>" +
                    "<status>sent</status>" +   // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account
                    // add document(s)
                    "<documents>" +
                    "<document>" +
                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                    "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" +
                    "</document>" +
                    "</documents>" +
                    // add recipient(s)
                    "<recipients>" +
                    "<signers>" +
                    "<signer>" +
                    "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                    "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                    "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                    "<tabs>" +
                    "<signHereTabs>" +
                    "<signHere>" +
                    "<anchorString>1SI</anchorString>" +
                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                    "</signHere>" +
                    "</signHereTabs>" +
                    "</tabs>" +
                    "</signer>" +
                    "<signer>" +
                    "<recipientId>2</recipientId>" +
                    "<email>someuser@mycompany.com</email>" +
                    "<name>Some User</name>" +
                    "<tabs>" +
                    "<signHereTabs>" +
                    "<signHere>" +
                    "<anchorString>2SI</anchorString>" +
                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                    "</signHere>" +
                    "</signHereTabs>" +
                    "</tabs>" +
                    "</signer>" +
                    "</signers>" +
                    "</recipients>" +
                    "</envelopeDefinition>";

                // set request url, method, headers.  Don't set the body yet, we'll set that separelty after
                // we read the document bytes and configure the rest of the multipart/form-data request
                request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", null, username, password, integratorKey);

                // some extra config for this api call
                configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(request, xmlBody, documentName, contentType);

                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(prettyPrintXml(text));
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        } // end main()

        //***********************************************************************************************
        // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
        //***********************************************************************************************
        public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;
            addRequestHeaders(request, email, password, intKey);
            if (body != null)
                addRequestBody(request, body);
            return request;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            // authentication header can be in JSON or XML format.  XML used for this walkthrough:
            string authenticateStr =
                "<DocuSignCredentials>" +
                    "<Username>" + email + "</Username>" +
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" +
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + intKey + "</IntegratorKey>" +
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";
            request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
        {
            // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
            byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(HttpWebRequest request, string xmlBody, string docName, string contentType)
        {
            // overwrite the default content-type header and set a boundary marker
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY";

            // start building the multipart request body
            string requestBodyStart = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" +
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" +
                    "\r\n" +
                    xmlBody + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +    // our xml formatted envelopeDefinition
                    "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
                    "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"" + docName + "\"; documentId=1\r\n" +
                    "\r\n";
            string requestBodyEnd = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n";

            // read contents of provided document into the request stream
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(docName);

            // write the body of the request
            byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyStart.ToString());
            byte[] bodyEnd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyEnd.ToString());
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, requestBodyStart.ToString().Length);

            // Read the file contents and write them to the request stream.  We read in blocks of 4096 bytes
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = fileStream.Read(buf, 0, 4096)) > 0)
            {
                dataStream.Write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            dataStream.Write(bodyEnd, 0, requestBodyEnd.ToString().Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            // read the response stream into a local string
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string parseDataFromResponse(string response, string searchToken)
        {
            // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == searchToken))
                        return reader.ReadString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string prettyPrintXml(string xml)
        {
            // print nicely formatted xml
            try
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                return doc.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return xml;
            }
        }
    } // end class
} // end namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to switch  to .  In this type of recipient, you identify a host by defining  and  in addition to who is actually signing the document .   is optional.

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/help is a great resource for looking at what is available in an API call, and you can find more information on what I provided above there under the POST {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes